# How does OS works - multitasking

Tags: process, operating-system, multitasking

it's probably really stupid question, but I'm learning about how Operating System works and I am confused. If OS perform multitasking by switching from one process to another than what about OS itself? It's also a process, isn't it?

Thank You very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The operating system kernel usually is not a process but rather is code that executes kernel mode while running a process.

One sequence for switching processes might be:

1. Timer interrupt goes off while running process P.
2. The timer interrupt handler gets executed in kernel mode by P.
3. The interrupt handler invokes the scheduler that determines process Q should execute.
4. The scheduler executes a change save process context instruction, saving the state of P.
5. The scheduler executes a load process context instruction, loading the state of Q. As soon as that instruction finishes executing Q is the running process.
6. The interrupt handler exits, returning control to Q where it was last executing.

Answer (score 1):

An Operating System has a component called the Scheduler that performs the function of switching among the application and other system threads (tasks). The Scheduler is almost always part of the OS kernel image which typically runs on a dedicated hardware thread of the processor once the OS has been loaded into memory by the Bootloader.

After the Scheduler releases a task to execute, it waits for a signal from its interrupt-controller hardware to tell it when to preempt (stop) the running task and release another task for execution. The details of how this occurs depend on the scheduling algorithm (e.g. Round-Robin, Time-Slicing, Earliest-Deadline-First, etc.) that the OS designer chose to implement. An OS with a time-slicing kernel, for example, will use interrupts from a hardware timer as the wake-up call for its Scheduler.